# How to get the value from a span tag using javascript or playwright tool?

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I have a `span` tag where we have a value 2 which keeps changing. I want to store this value in a variable either using javascript or playwright (a testing tool).

```
<span class="dynamic classname" data-testid="typography">2</span>
```

Note: Even class name is not constant.

```
const count = document.getElementByTagName('span');
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Using playwright:

```
const element = await page.locator('[data-testid="typography"]');
const count = await element.getAttraibute(element);
```

I'm new to javascript and playwright, any lead would be helpful.

Comment: If the target element has no unique characteristics to select by, then target it by using the parent HTML structure, eg. `document.querySelector('#container #nav .foo-container > span').dataset.testid`

Comment: You have a typo in function name. It should be document.getElementsByTagName('span')

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski also getAttraibute, I don't know `page.locator` selector support, but `document.querySelector('[data-testid="typography"]')` will work

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
const count = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText;
```

[more examples](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Playwright

```
const element = await page.locator('[data-testid="typography"]');
const count = await element.innerText();
```

see [innerText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-inner-text)